# Device name/id doesnt show in organizer window

Tags: iphone, xcode, provisioning

I have added a device via the provsiong portal by enetering the UDID

But when viewing the device in the organizer window in xcode, it just shows "1 other device," and not the same info as for other devices I have added. I get the feeling that it is not really added?!

Note the other devices that come up normally where added via usb cable and using the organizer window.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is this for an Ad Hoc distribution? Is that why you're worried?  What version of XCode are you using? (I can't see the screenshot due to my lack of Google credentials)

Comment: Google-Link: "Sorry, the page (or document) you have requested is not available. Please check the address and try again."

Comment: Can you reattach a new link to the image, as google says: "Sorry, the page (or document) you have requested is not available. Please check the address and try again."

Comment: https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0BwKJCmBpCbSGY2U2YjJiNGEtZGI5Ny00YWZiLTkxM2YtNGJhNzM5ZDhhOGRj&hl=en&authkey=COLzs_kI            that image should work

Answer (score 0):

In organizer select the "other device", right click and select the option named similar to "use for development".
Xcode will retrieve some information form the "other device" and after a few seconds will show the new device like the other devices

Comment: clarification i try to select the device in the organizer provisioning profiles view

Comment: ah right. Goto to the "DEVICES" part, above "DEVELOPMENT". There you should have a not yet ready iphone. The provisioning profile window will tell you the device that your xcode has successfully installed to directly. "Directly" as in physically connected to your Mac. The "other device" is a UDID of a phone that your xcode has never connected to but that is present in the AdHoc profile.

Comment: i dont see the not yet ready device under the devices section. It is only available under development/provisioning profiles.  How does that phone receive the provisioning profiles it belongs to? do i have to send them and they will add manually via itunes?

Comment: yes. Alternatively, when doing a build and Archive, choose share, then resign with the Adhoc certificate. If you don't see your device under DEVICES there is something wrong along the line of xcode - MAC - cable - iphone

Comment: Thanks for the help...   Just be sure i tried opening the provision profile with a text editor and verifiying that the UDID is actually in the profile, and it is. So it seems that the prov. profile has the correct UDID it's just that it shows up greyed out in organizer. Maybe it can't retrieve info on the device as i added it via provisioning portal? only devices added manually (via cable) show up non greyed out and with device name?